# Japanese visa for American

Tags: visas, japan, us-citizens, visa-free-entry

I am an American flying into Narita from Taiwan with connecting flight to US same day at Haneda airport. Do I need a visa?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, you don't need a visa for visits of under 90 days.

Source: https://www.us.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/travel_and_visa.html

Comment: ...as of now. Due to the quickly developing pandemic, Japan may suspend their VWP for U.S. citizens, as they have done for South Korea citizens, if the situation in the U.S. escalates.

Comment: Normally this wouldn't be a concern, but COVID-19 makes this an imminent and real possibility.